# how to move WordPress website from subdomain to main domain with more quickly

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

I created a new website using a subdomain but now I want to move this site to the main domain without time-consuming (more quickly)

Example :
subdomain : new.google.com
main domain :google.com

I need to move them without time-consuming because my customer has trouble with order the product.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this thing

1. move all file to root directory (public_html) with .htacces file
2. duplicate db if you needed
3. update wp-config.php with new db credential
4. change home url and site url (sub domain url to main domain url)in database
5. you can use a plugin for change all old url to new url in your site
   I have used https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ this plugin for change URL, it was working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

contact customer service where you host your site!  , if you buy a domain at the same place you only need to point the domain to your web server, otherwise you have to change the dns record where you bought the domain and point it to your web hosting place, you should contact customer service where you are hosting for better help